# Send list in HTTP Request in particular order taking order by as row num?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, httprequest, list

Apex code:

```
    List<order_batch__c> bcList = new List<order_batch__c>();
        bcList= [select Order_numbering__c,Or_clientpn__c,Or_customerid__c,Or_customer_PO_Number__c,Or_Nicomatic_p_n__c,Or_Quote_number__c,Quantity_Ordered__c,Quote_Line_Item__c,Requested_Date__c,Unit_price__c,Or_Carrier__c,Or_orderdate__c from order_batch__c  where  Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__c= : Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')];
        String JSONString = JSON.serialize(bclist);
```

visualforcecode:

```
    <apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header">S.NO</apex:facet>
     <apex:outputText value="{!FLOOR(rowNum)}"/>
     <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum + 1}"/></apex:column>
<apex:column ><button onClick="MoveUp();">&#8679;</button></apex:column>
</apex:column><button onClick="MoveDown();">&#8681;</button></apex:column>
```

I am send a list through http request .I am using row num option for numbering .According to the customer po they want to change the order so that i am using javascript to change the items up and down .According to that row num is changing .

The problem how can i define the rownum in my list order.

Thanks in advance:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think wrapping this would be ideal if indexing of list is needed

```
public class OrderBtachWrapper(){

  public order_batch__c orderbatch{get;set}
  public integer rowno{get;set;}

}
integer c=0;
List< OrderBtachWrapper> lstOrderWrapper=new List< OrderBtachWrapper>();
for(order_batch__c o:[selectOrder_numbering__c,Or_clientpn__c,Or_customerid__c,Or_customer_PO_Number__c,Or_Nicomatic_p_n__c,Or_Quote_number__c,Quantity_Ordered__c,Quote_Line_Item__c,Requested_Date__c,Unit_price__c,Or_Carrier__c,Or_orderdate__c from order_batch__c  where  Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__c= : Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')];){
       OrderBtachWrapper obatch=new OrderBtachWrapper();
      obatch.orderbatch=obatch;
     obatch.rowno=c;
    c=c+1;
    lstOrderWrapper.add(obatch);


}

 String JSONString = JSON.serialize(lstOrderWrapper.add);
```